# Getting original sequence from a random permutation in python

Tags: python, permutation

Is there a way to get back the original sequence from a random permutation in **python**?

For example, the original sequence is `p1=[4,1,8,2,3]`

and the random permutation generated is `p2=[8,3,1,4,2]`

Is there a way to get back `p1` using `p2`?

**EDIT:** sorry my question seemed unclear

I have to get back p1 using `p2` in a different program where I don't have access to `p1`

For example,

```
import random
p1=[4,1,8,2,3]
p2=p1[:]
random.seed(10)
random.shuffle(p2)
print(p2)  #prints [2, 8, 1, 4, 3]
```

Is there a way to get back `p1` using `p2` in a different program where I don't have access to `p1`?

Comment: _random permutation generated_ - generated how? Also, note _sequence_ is not necessarily ordered one. Anyway - if it's really random, I don't see how you will get the original one, or the link between the two is not random.

Comment: If you know the "index" of the permutation it may be possible to reverse engineer the original sequence

Comment: And since you already have `p1` , I really dont understand the new of re constructing the same list using `p2`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. But essentially you need a structure to keep track of the original places of your `p1` elements

For which you can use a `dict` to achieve it

```
p1 = [4,1,8,2,3]
p2 = [8,3,1,4,2]
refHash_p1 = {k:i for i,k in enumerate(p1)}

p3 = sorted(p2,key=lambda x:refHash_p1[x])

>>> p3
[4, 1, 8, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you also know the random permutation that was applied in one abstract way or another, in for [example cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation)  . Otherwise how would you distinguish between p2 coming from p1 or p2 coming from [1,2,3,4,8]